# Dynamic width on table child

Tags: html, css

I had a problem making an responsive width of element that attributed with `display:table-cell` or element `<td>` itself, i have a parent element `<div class="parent">` with few child written below

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

And written few lines of css codes like below

```
.parent {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.parent .child {
    display: table-cell;
    width : 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

The problem is, the first child will have 100% of parent width, which the other two got 0% width, i try to devide and change the css codes like this

```
.parent .child {
    display: table-cell;
    width : 33%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

It did work fine, but the things that i really want is to devide the width of the parent dinamicly, depending of the amount of the child, i mean it's not staticly like that, sometimes 3 sometimes 5 and etc.

Maybe i can count the amount of the child using js `elementParent.childElementCount` and devide the 100% by the amount of the child to give into each other child width using JavaScript, but how if i only using css?

Thanks for any correction.

Comment: Have you tried `display: flex`?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply width as in child div 'auto'

```
 .parent .child {
      display: table-cell;
      width : auto;
      padding: 5px;
                }
```

Let me know if this meets your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

> ```
> .parent {
>     ...
>   table-layout: fixed;
> }
> .parent .child {
>     ...
>   overflow-x: hidden;
>   word-break: break-word;
> }
> ```

This combination makes the "table" distribute the widths of each "cell" evenly. Added to the demo is some JavaScript that adds extra cells to demonstrate the behavior previously described.

---

### Demo

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = addCell;

function addCell(e) {
  var table = document.querySelector('.parent');
  table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <div class="child">XX</div>`);
}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.parent .child {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  word-break: break-word;
}

button {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</div>
  <div class="child">XX</div>
  <div class="child">XX</div>
</div>

<button>Add Cell</button>
```